# Using Haskell Math.Combinatorics.Species to enumerate partitions

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

The following interaction shows how to enumerate the subsets of a set using the latest (version 0.4) of the Math.Combinatorics.Species library available for Haskell. I would like to figure out how to use the same library to enumerate partitions of a set, but I cannot understand and fix the type errors I get. More specifically, I do not understand the structureType of partition, what does ": Set Set" mean?

```
vamsi@vamsi-laptop:~/learn/project_euler$ ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> import qualified Math.Combinatorics.Species as S
S> import qualified Data.Int as I
S I> S.structureType S.subset
"Set"
S I> S.enumerate S.subset [1,2,3] :: [S.Set I.Int]
[{},{3},{2},{2,3},{1},{1,3},{1,2},{1,2,3}]
S I> S.structureType S.partition
": Set Set"
S I> S.enumerate S.partition [1,2,3] :: [S.Set (S.Set I.Int)]

<interactive>:6:26: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.Num.Num (S.Set I.Int))
      arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1
      In the second argument of ‘S.enumerate’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3]’
      In the expression:
      S.enumerate S.partition [1, 2, 3] :: [S.Set (S.Set I.Int)]
S I> S.enumerate S.partition [1,2,3] :: [(S.Set I.Int)]
[{*** Exception: Structure type mismatch.
Expected: Set Int
Inferred: : Set Set Int
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Math/Combinatorics/Species/Enumerate.hs:176:33 in 
  species-0.4-DcNHk9r6nze3hHzRydgNb3:Math.Combinatorics.Species.Enumerate
```

Comment: Oh dear. I suspect the `dropQuals` function which is intended to discard module names, e.g. turning `Math.Combinatorics.Species.Set` into just `Set`, is malfunctioning and turning the type constructor `:.:` into just `:`. What happens if you use `S.enumerate S.partition [1,2,3] :: [(S.Set S.:.: S.Set) I.Int]`?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It worked!! =====> `vamsi@vamsi-laptop:~/learn/project_euler/257_to_384/problem_259$ ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude -XTypeOperators`
`GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help`
`> import qualified Math.Combinatorics.Species as S`
`S> import qualified Data.Int as I`
`S I> S.enumerate S.partition [1,2,3] :: [(S.Set S.:.: S.Set) I.Int]`
`[{{1,2,3}},{{2,3},{1}},{{2},{1,3}},{{3},{1,2}},{{3},{2},{1}}]`

Comment: @DanielWagner Could you be bothered to open an [issue](https://github.com/byorgey/species/issues) so that everyone benefits from this discovery?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov No need to get aggressive. I just wanted to make sure I had the right solution before taking action. Normally I do that by installing the appropriate packages into a sandbox and testing myself, but I wasn't in a position where I could do that last night.

Comment: @DanielWagner I did not mean to be aggressive at all; I'm sorry if it sounded so. English is my second language; I must have missed some nuance.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Oh, great! Sorry I read that into your message, then. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a bug in the pretty-printer used by `structureType`. I've reported the problem [here](https://github.com/byorgey/species/issues/3); in the meantime, you should probably use `:.:` any time you see just `:` as a type constructor. So, like this:

```
S I> S.enumerate S.partition [1,2,3] :: [(S.Set S.:.: S.Set) I.Int]
[{{1,2,3}},{{2,3},{1}},{{2},{1,3}},{{3},{1,2}},{{3},{2},{1}}]
```